# Jetson TK1 / OpenCV4Tegra Linker errors

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, tegra

I've got a program that compiles / runs fine on my machine.  I just picked up a Nvidia Jetson TK1 to try running it on that.  I flashed to the latest version of linux4tegra, installed cuda and opencv per the instruction [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/L4T/r21_Release_v3.0/l4t_quick_start_guide.txt) and [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/OpenCV/L4T_21.1/README.txt).  I'm getting linker errors whenever I try to run my make file:

```
(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::string const&)'
(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::VideoCapture'
(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::VideoCapture'
```

I already symlinked a few cuda SO's, but I can't figure out where these are coming from.

My makefile looks like:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs opencv` ...
```

Package config returns:

```
$ pkg-config --libs opencv
/usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/lib/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/lib/libopencv_esm_panorama.so /usr/lib/libopencv_facedetect.so /usr/lib/libopencv_imuvstab.so /usr/lib/libopencv_tegra.so /usr/lib/libopencv_vstab.so -lcufft -lnpps -lnppi -lnppc -lcudart -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Any ideas?  My initial though was header / SO mismatch but since these all came from nvidia in the same package I think that's unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed `pkg-config --libs opencv` after my files in the make file.